# Multi-pane browser window with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, browser, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to implement a project in VB.NET wherein a user can see two browser window panes side by side. It is very similar to placing two browser windows side by side on the screen, one docking to the left side, and the other on the right side. Only in this case, there's only one application. I'm having the following problems with my code

1. On pressing enter, the browser is not navigating to the website for both the panes
2. The controls on the left pane are not working. Only the Go button works for the left pane.

Here is my code (can't post pictures yet):

Public Class Form1

```
    Dim int As Integer = 0
    Dim int1 As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Loading(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Forms.WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs)
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = e.MaximumProgress
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = e.MaximumProgress
    End Sub
    Private Sub Loading1(ByVal sender1 As Object, ByVal e1 As Windows.Forms.WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs)
        ToolStripProgressBar2.Maximum = e1.MaximumProgress
        ToolStripProgressBar2.Value = e1.MaximumProgress
    End Sub
    Private Sub Done(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).DocumentTitle
        TextBox1.Text = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Url.ToString
    End Sub
    Private Sub Done1(ByVal sender1 As Object, ByVal e1 As Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        TabControl2.SelectedTab.Text = CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).DocumentTitle
        TextBox2.Text = CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Url.ToString
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page")
        Browser.Name = "Web Browser"
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
        AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
        AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done
        int = int + 1
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
        Dim Browser1 As New WebBrowser
        TabControl2.TabPages.Add("New Page")
        Browser1.Name = "Web Browser 2"
        Browser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser1)
        AddHandler Browser1.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading1
        AddHandler Browser1.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done1
        int1 = int1 + 1
        CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page")
        TabControl1.SelectTab(int)
        Browser.Name = "Web Browser"
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
        AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
        AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done
        int = int + 1
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Not TabControl1.TabPages.Count = 1 Then
            TabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(TabControl1.SelectedIndex)
            TabControl1.SelectTab(TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1)
            int = int - 1
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).ShowPropertiesDialog()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).GoBack()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).GoForward()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Refresh()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Stop()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).StatusText
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button17_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button17.Click
        Dim Browser1 As New WebBrowser
        TabControl2.TabPages.Add("New Page")
        TabControl2.SelectTab(int1)
        Browser1.Name = "Web Browser 2"
        Browser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser1)
        AddHandler Browser1.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading1
        AddHandler Browser1.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done1
        int1 = int1 + 1
        CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button15_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
        If Not TabControl2.TabPages.Count = 1 Then
            TabControl2.TabPages.RemoveAt(TabControl2.SelectedIndex)
            TabControl2.SelectTab(TabControl2.TabPages.Count - 1)
            int1 = int1 - 1
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(TextBox2.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
        CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).ShowPropertiesDialog()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
        CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).GoBack()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button11_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).GoForward()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
        CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Refresh()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button14_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click
        CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Stop()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button16_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button16.Click
        CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button18_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
        CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(TextBox2.Text)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).StatusText
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm new here so I'm sorry if I missed out anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**: I tried implementing the same thing with a single pane, much like implementing a simple tabbed browser in Visual Studio 2013. Same result. Only GO button works, and enter key does not produce anything.

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that my subs weren't handling anything.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>     If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
>         CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
>     End If
> ```

You only calling navigate in TabControl1 (or 2). You need to call all from each of the TextBoxX_KeyDown Handlers.

> ```
>     If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
>         CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
>         CType(TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(TextBox2.Text)
>     End If
> ```